# PHPMailer SMTP Error: Could not authenticate Mercury localhost

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Currently I'm testing my email format and email send on localhost. I use XAMPP and have 'set up' Mercury mail server. I didn't change anything and made a new user.

Here's a pic of the local users:

[image]

Then, I have this in PHP (not all the code but the important part):

```
$mailer = new mailer\Mailer();
$mailer->setCustomSettings();
// Some addAddress, From, subject and content variables are set here....
$mailer->send();
```

And then `setCustomSettings` look like this:

```
public function setCustomSettings() {
    $this->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $this->isSMTP();
    $this->Host = 'localhost';
    $this->SMTPAuth = true;
    $this->Username = 'Admin';
    $this->Password = '*******';

    //$this->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $this->Port = 25;
    $this->imapHost = '127.0.0.1';
}
```

Now, I hoped it'd work but unfortunately it doesn't. I get the following error:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'mailer\phpmailerException' with message 'SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.' in D:\xampp\htdocs\FOLDER\classes\mailer\PHPMailer.php:1352
```

I know my password is correct, you can see the user exists and I can login on Roundcube on my email.

With `SMTPDebug` I get the following output:

```
2017-03-27 07:57:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 localhost ESMTP server ready.
2017-03-27 07:57:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO SOMENAME.local
2017-03-27 07:57:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-localhost Hello SOMENAME.local; ESMTPs are:
                                  250-TIME
                                  250-SIZE 0
                                  250 HELP
2017-03-27 07:57:18 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2017-03-27 07:57:18 SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 localhost Service closing channel.
2017-03-27 07:57:18 SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

Comment: try to enable the debugger using `$this->SMTPDebug  = 2;`

Comment: See my edited post for the output.

Comment: try to specify the `Username = "root@localhost"`

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

This shows that there is something missing on your mail server. This is the list of capabilities it says it supports:

```
250-TIME
250-SIZE 0
250 HELP
```

Notice that this list does not include the `AUTH` extension, but you've asked PHPMailer to authenticate, but it can't because your server does not support authentication, so it gives up. To compare, this is what Gmail says (after STARTTLS):

```
250-smtp.gmail.com at your service
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
```

You can see that it lists a whole load of `AUTH` mechanisms.

You should be able to solve this by simply disabling authentication:

```
$this->SMTPAuth = false;
```

or by altering the config of your mail server so that it offers authentication.

While I'm here, why don't you put what's in your `setCustomSettings()` method into a constructor method, so you don't need to call it?

Comment: I haven't changed it yet, I was just trying things first. I didn't make that function. I know it works when `$this->SMTPAuth` is false, but I'd rather have it on. I'll see if I can find something for AUTH on Mercury.